# Javascript String Replace - RegEx for Non-Alphanumeric Characters Like Backslash, Greater Than, etc

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, character

I have a string that was serialized from the DOM world and I want to find some closing tags in that string and replace them with a new string. I never know the length of that original string, so character counts etc. will not work here. A sample scenario:

```
var onetext = "</content><tag>A whole bunch of stuff</tag></message>"
var twotext = "</content><tag>A whole bunch of new, unrelated stuff</tag></message>"
var threetext = onetext.replace(/[\/<]/\\/content>.+</message>/,"</content>"+twotext+"</message>");
```

I clearly don't have the regular expressions right to find these instances of backslash, greater-than or less-than. I welcome anyone's help in getting this to run correctly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, there is a way to do this with one line

You can use grouping identifiers in your replacements string like this:

```
'<foo>Some data</foo>'.replace(/(<foo>)(.+)(<\/foo>)/,'<bar>$2</bar>')
```

However, at the end of the day, if you ONLY want to replace closing tags, just replace those, don't worry about the rest of the content, unless you need to pass that through as well.  If you are only looking at ... then this is the expression you need:

```
/<\/content>.+<\/message>/
```

Comment: I'm running into different problems with the web service's ingestion of the replaced string, but not because your first replace example didn't work (oddly, I could not get the second suggestion, which is closer to how I formulated the question, to work at all). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to capture everything that is NOT an allowed character, then write your expression for that.

Here is an expression for that (keeps number, letter and spaces, rejects everything else):
(?![a-zA-Z0-9 ]).

If you are looking for something specific to HTML tags, you want (catches open and close tags):

([\<]|[/>])

Comment: Thanks, but I'm also trying to leverage the `.+` to take everything between those tags and then drop in my replacement, i.e. make my string replace constructor "look" like: `.replace(</content>.+</message>,"</content>"+twotext+"</message>")` at least as far as string.replace and RegEx are concerned. I'm not sure how I'd utilize your suggestion in that scenario.

Comment: You can't do that with regular expressions on one line.  Your best bet is to do two passes, one to replace the open tags, and one to replace the close tags.  `var onetext = "</content><tag>A whole bunch of stuff</tag></message>";
var twotext = "</content><tag>A whole bunch of new, unrelated stuff</tag></message>";
var threetext = onetext.replace(/<content>/,'<message>');
threetext = threetext.replace(/<\/content>/,'</message>');
alert(treetext);`

Comment: I used onetext/twotext/threetext scenario (which you misspell as 'treetext' in your example, and don't seem to use twotext) as an example - sadly, I'll never know what is between </content> and </message> in the first string, so need a wildcard. Which I thought I found here: [link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html) - if I try "</content>[\s\S]*</message>" there, it replaces strings correctly, but `var sendlesson = usertext.replace(new RegExp("\\</content>[\s\S]*</message>", "gm"), "</content>" + textvar + "</message>");` won't work ('textvar' does have text). Sigh...

Comment: First response FTW -- though any guidance on RegEx is hugely helpful to me. All those slashes/backslashes make my eyes seize up and it's difficult for me to figure just what is being expressed.